# Should I capitalize more specific topic/field such as Computational Science and Discrete Math?

Tags: capitalization

Should I capitalize abstract topics such as  Discrete Math, Data Structures, Graph Theory, Computational Physics, Artificial Neural Network, Natural Language Processing?

I know that specific course names such as *Physics 101, English 102*,and *History of Economics and Welfare 106* should be capitalized, and on the other hand, chemistry, physics, and literature should not be capitalized. But Graph Theory seems to lie in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the rule [found here](http://www.bc.edu/offices/omc/styleguide/capitalization.html) is academic subjects are lower case unless they are the name of a language, culture, or religion.

> He is taking math, literature, and English this semester.

Also you should capitalize if it is the formal name of a department at some institution, or on an official diploma or degree.

> His work is in graph theory and data structures, but he has an Electrical Engineering degree.

[More information](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6246/capitalize-fields-of-study)